# solana/web3.js connection not working : fetch Failed

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch-api

```
const connection = new web3.Connection(
    web3.clusterApiUrl('testnet',false),
    'confirmed',
  );
  console.log(await connection.getBlockTime());
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12442:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ClientBrowser.callServer (/mnt/d/solang/hello/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6454:17) {  cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
      at onConnectTimeout (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7595:28)
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7551:50
      at Immediate._onImmediate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7583:13)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
  }
}
```

I was expecting to get the blocktime

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?? I'm experiencing it massively.